# C++ most common parallel processing method. Pthreads?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, pthreads

Just need some insight over parallel processing methods on C++. My work on parallelizing untill now , has been on C, where the main method is using pthreads.

However I've also worked with openMP and cilkPlus.

I just want to ask , what is the common way of parallelizing code in C++ ? Are pthreads considered to be a good or bad implementation ? Shall I continue using them in C++ ?

Comment: satarting c++11 there is a standard thread package in the stl library which you can use instead of pthreads. Or you can continue using pthreads instead.

Comment: I think this is probably too broad and opinion based because different techniques for different situations. But `C++` has a standard threading library now that is bound to be popular. `pthreads` is a great implementation but it does not take advantage of standard `C++` techniques that provide things like exception safety and RAII resource management.

Comment: In the case of Windows, and some other operating systems there's [WaitForMultipleObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025(v=vs.85).aspx) or something equivalent. This requires using Windows native threads or processes. Linux doesn't include an equivalent function and requires some type of workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ delivers concurrency in its standard library at different layers of abstraction.
The most low-level approach to threads is the use of std::thread in conjunction with the synchronization classes std::mutex, std::unique_lock, std::condition_variable etc. Furthermore, there is support for atomic operations (compare_exchange_weak/strong, fetch_add and alike), including memory ordering facilities like fences.

The next higher level of abstraction makes use of std::async, std::future and std::promise. Instead of having to control several threads on one's own here one just focusses on the execution of tasks, which may be sequential or parallel, whatever suits the most in the specific situation. The implementation even may decide on its own when to work parallel or not.


Finally, in C++17, there are concurrent implementations of known sequential STL-algorithms that use concurrency internally, like std::for_each and std::reduce which behaves similar to std::accumulate. This in conjunction with yet to come features, such as coroutines, ranges and execution contexts, can lead to very robust, performant and especially readable code. 

Summarizing, there are several *portable* tools for parallel programming in C++. As with everything in programming, one should use the most abstract tool one can get in order to prevent dealing with details not relevant for the actual problem. Therefore, unless there is a good reason, I would not use pthreads in C++ any longer.

Answer (score 1):

As a first choice, unless your needs are more complex, use `std::thread`, `std::mutex`, `std::condition_variable` etc

see documentation here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/thread

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/mutex

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/future

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/condition_variable

The standard thread tools are not fantastic or bleeding edge, but they are *good enough* for most tasks - certainly as a replacement for pthreads.

The advantage of the `std::` constructs is that visibility of changes to shared data is guaranteed to be correct, even when the optimiser reorders loads and stores as part of its as-if pass.

If your needs are more complex, then building concurrency tools, or using a library that it built on top of them is a good idea.